# DataFX - how to get Parent?

Tags: javafx

Trying to start using DataFX ,, i wanna load an FXML view into another Pane,  so i have a stage that is showing, on user action will add another FXML view to a Pane on the showing stage,

i usually do that this way :

```
fxmlLoader = constructFXMLLoader(FXMLPath);
root = (Parent) this.fxmlLoader.load();


private FXMLLoader constructFXMLLoader(String FXMLPath) {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    fxmlLoader.setLocation(getURL(stageFXMLName));
    fxmlLoader.setBuilderFactory(new JavaFXBuilderFactory());

    return fxmlLoader;
}
```

there i have the root so i can add it where ever i want, the question is how to do that with DataFX

i did a quick research but found nothing !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just figured out the answer

```
FlowHandler flowHandler = new Flow(Controller.class).createHandler();
    flowHandler.getCurrentView().getViewContext().getRootNode();
```